# Htaccess que direciona para https e também para www

Tags: htaccess, apache, redirecionamento

Preciso que quando o user acessa com `http` seja direcionado para `https` e quando acessa sem `www` redireciona para acessar com `www`.

Estou utilizando o seguinte código no `.htaccess`:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]

  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
  RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
           
</IfModule>
 
<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
  # If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
  # can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.
  # Submitted by: ElliotHaughin
 
  ErrorDocument 404 /index.php

</IfModule>

# php -- BEGIN cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
# NOTE this account's php is controlled via FPM and the vhost, this is a place holder.
# Do not edit. This next line is to support the cPanel php wrapper (php_cli).
# AddType application/x-httpd-ea-php56 .php .phtml
# php -- END cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
```

Segue o código que eu estava utilizando:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]

  # Redireciona para o HTTPS independente do domínio
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
  RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

  # Adiciona www. no prefixo do domínio
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
  RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

</IfModule>
 
<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
  # If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
  # can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.
  # Submitted by: ElliotHaughin
 
  ErrorDocument 404 /index.php

</IfModule>

# php -- BEGIN cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
# NOTE this account's php is controlled via FPM and the vhost, this is a place holder.
# Do not edit. This next line is to support the cPanel php wrapper (php_cli).
# AddType application/x-httpd-ea-php56 .php .phtml
# php -- END cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
```

O problema é que, quando utilizo este segundo código, ele funciona em partes. Quando acesso uma página interna, ele joga na url um `index.php?/` e às vezes entra em loop infinito.

Alguém já precisou fazer algo semelhante?

Answer (score 1):

Basicamente isso:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.endereco\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.endereco.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

- `RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on [OR]` só redireciona se não for https, OU
- `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.ende...` se não tiver `www` no começo.

Answer (score 0):

Isso deve resolver seu problema

`RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)(.+) [OR]
 RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?(.+)
 RewriteRule ^ https://%2%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]`