# NON-WWW | Force HTTPS | Subdominios

Tags: apache, htaccess, https

Estou há dias com problemas em configurar meu *htaccess*. Já tentei muitas configurações que encontrei pela internet e inclusive algumas daqui e nenhum sucesso.

Preciso que no meu htaccess eu tenha as seguintes caracteristicas:

- Sempre usar HTTPS
- Sempre usar NON-WWW
- E que isso não afete meus subdominios

Digo isso pq preciso usar subdominios e não consigo pois as **regras atuais** que tenho no htaccess redirecionam tudo sempre para o dominio principal.

Quero já deixar registrado que as configuracoes no painel de DNS estão feitas com entradas do tipo "A" apontando para o ip do meu servidor.

Meu servidor é na locaweb, usando o Jelastic.

Abaixo segue as minhas regras atuais de htaccess e mais abaixo minha configuração no Apache.

### **HTACCESS**

```
RewriteEngine           On
Options                 +FollowSymlinks
RewriteBase             /

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301]
```

**APACHE**
<**Bloco 01 - Virtual Host**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/webroot/PASTA_SUBDOMINIO
    ServerName  subdominio.dominioprincipal.com.br
    ServerAlias subdominios.dominioprincipal.com.br
</VirtualHost>
```

**Bloco 02 - Virtual Host**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/webroot/ROOT
    ServerName meusite.jelastic.com
    ServerAlias dominioprincipal.com.br
</VirtualHost>
```

Só quero poder acessar por exemplo subdominio.dominioprincipal.com.br e ficar sem o WWW, usar o HTTPS e cair na pasta correta dentro do servidor... mas tá dificil. :(

Não consegui inserir de forma bonitinha os trechos de códigos mas acho que dá para entender.

Conseguem me dar uma luz nesse maldito htaccess? hahahaha

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Htaccess que direciona para https e também para www](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/267877/htaccess-que-direciona-para-https-e-tamb%c3%a9m-para-www) (entre várias outras. esse é um assunto cheio de duplicatas, vai encontrar dezenas de variações na busca)

Comment: A pergunta sugerida como já respondida não resolveu meu problema. :/

Comment: E você pesquisou outras variantes? Bem provável que nessa busca (atualmente com 295 resultados) você encontre a solução: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bhtaccess%5D+https